# AWK - lookup and replace multiple fields using multiple files

Tags: awk

Having trouble working out what I need to achieve in AWK. I have 2 files:

File1

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|AAA|BBB|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|CCC|DDD|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|EEE|FFF|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|GGG|HHH|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|III|JJJ|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|KKK|LLL|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|MMM|NNN|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|OOO|PPP|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QQQ|RRR|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|SSS|TTT|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|UUU|VVV|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|WWW|XXX|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|YYY|ZZZ|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QWE|RTY|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASD|FGH|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ZXC|VBN|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASS|BOB|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|FFR|ERD|12|13|
```

File2

```
AAA|BBB|AA1|BB1|
CCC|DDD|CC1|DD1|
EEE|FFF|EE1|FF1|
GGG|HHH|GG1|HH1|
III|JJJ|II1|JJ1|
KKK|LLL|KK1|LL1|
MMM|NNN|MM1|NN1|
OOO|PPP|OO1|PP1|
QQQ|RRR|QQ1|RR1|
SSS|TTT|SS1|TT1|
```

I need to replace fields 10 and 11 in file 1 with fields 3 and 4 from file 2 where fields 10 and 11 in file 1 equal fields 1 and 2 in file 2.

So my desired output fot this example would be:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|AA1|BB1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|CC1|DD1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|EE1|FF1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|GG1|HH1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|II1|JJ1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|KK1|LL1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|MM1|NN1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|OO1|PP1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QQ1|RR1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|SS1|TT1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|UUU|VVV|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|WWW|XXX|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|YYY|ZZZ|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QWE|RTY|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASD|FGH|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ZXC|VBN|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASS|BOB|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|FFR|ERD|12|13|
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your real file fixed lenght too ? or is it just for the idea and fields could have variable lenght ?

Comment: Hi, no the real file has varying field lengths.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106645/processing-two-files-using-awk could help you I think. I can't write an answer right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this make it?

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3; b[$1,$2]=$4; next}
    ($10,$11) in a {f10=a[$10,$11];$11=b[$10,$11];$10=f10}
    1' f2 f1
```

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3; b[$1,$2]=$4; next} ($10,$11) in a {f10=a[$10,$11];$11=b[$10,$11];$10=f10}1' f2 f1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|AA1|BB1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|CC1|DD1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|EE1|FF1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|GG1|HH1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|II1|JJ1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|KK1|LL1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|MM1|NN1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|OO1|PP1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QQ1|RR1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|SS1|TT1|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|UUU|VVV|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|WWW|XXX|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|YYY|ZZZ|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|QWE|RTY|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASD|FGH|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ZXC|VBN|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|ASS|BOB|12|13|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|FFR|ERD|12|13|
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` set input and output field separators to `|`.
- `FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3; b[$1,$2]=$4; next}` while reading the first file given (`f2`), store 3rd field in the array `a[]` and 4th field in array `b[]` with index given by the pair `($1,$2)`.
- `($10,$11) in a {f10=a[$10,$11];$11=b[$10,$11];$10=f10}` while looping through the second file given (`f1`), check if the pair `($10,$11)` was stored in the array `a[]`. If so, do the replacement. Otherwise, lines will keep as they were.
- `1` as per True condition, print the current line.

Comment: Something like `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2]=$3 FS $4; next} ($10 FS $11) in a {$10=a[$10 FS $11];$11=""}1' f2 f1` could also be done, storing everything by `$1 FS $2` indexes. Anyway, this leads to an extra `|`.